# TYPO3 loading default language instead of translation

Tags: localization, typo3, translation, multiple-languages

I'm using TYPO3 (with no other choice for the moment) and I have to add a secondary language to the website.

I have 2 languages:

- Default : English (en) set as L = 0
- English US (en_US) set as L = 1

I've made the change in the RealUrl and in the main template.

> ```
> config.sys_language_uid = 0
> config.language = en
> config.locale_all = en_US.UTF-8
> page.config.language = en
>
> config.linkVars = L
>
> [GLOBAL]
>
> [globalVar = GP:L = 1]
>   config {
>     sys_language_uid = 1
>     htmlTag_langKey  = en_US
>     language = en_US
>     locale_all = en_US.UTF-8
>   }
> [end]
>
> [GLOBAL]
> ```

And

> ```
> 'preVars' => array(
>       array(
>                 'GETvar' => 'no_cache',
>                 'valueMap' => array(
>                     'no_cache' => 1,
>                 ),
>                 'noMatch' => 'bypass',
>             ),
>             array(
>                 'GETvar' => 'L',
>                 'valueMap' => array(
>                     'en' => '0',
>                     'en_US' => '1',
>                 ),
>                 'noMatch' => 'bypass',
>                 'valueDefault' => 'en',
>             ),
>     ),
> ```

So far, my language is created, both the original and the translation of my page appear on the Page Editing of TYPO3.

The URL works (www.mywebsite.com/en_US/mypage.html).

From this point it doesn't work anymore :
The page is generated, with the good URL, but loading the default language content. 
(even with the preview test www.mywebsite.com/index.php?id=123&L=1 is not loading the good content)

Did I miss something ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved:

Forgot to precise the Original translation in the Page Edition

Select the original in the list (Transl.Orig) of the "General" tab of page editing.