# TYPO3 - Translation doesn't show, always default language

Tags: typo3, translation, typo3-8.x

([TYPO3 loading default language instead of translation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44840988/typo3-loading-default-language-instead-of-translation)) -> same story, but I can't fix it.

I do not have much experience in TYPO3 and I have the following problem at the moment.

Standard language is Dutch and I want a French translation. I have already translated a menu + page into French.

When I click on 'FR' (French) in the language select menu, the URL of index.php? Id = 215 & L = 0 changes to index.php? Id = 215 & L = 1, but the content remains in Futch.

I have srt_languagemenu installed and configured so that when the translation is not available, the language reference in the menu disappears. This works perfectly.

When I click on 'Save and open' from the backend after I did the translation, the normal standard (Dutch) page is also shown here.

Can someone tell me what I might do wrong or forgot to set?

TYPO3: 8.7.16

Thanks!

```
# Language Settings
# Default Language settings
config {
  linkVars = L(0-1)
  sys_language_uid = 0
  sys_language_overlay = 0  
  sys_language_mode = content_fallback
  page.config.language = nl
  language = nl
  locale_all = nl_NL.UTF-8
  htmlTag_langKey = nl
  htmlTag_setParams = lang="nl" dir="ltr" class="no-js"
}


# Language Frans
[globalVar = GP:L = 1]
config {
  sys_language_uid = 1
  htmlTag_langKey  = fr_FR
  language = fr_FR
  locale_all = fr_FR.UTF-8
  htmlTag_setParams = lang="fr" dir="ltr" class="no-js"
}
[global]   


# REALURL
config.baseURL = {$siteUrl}
config.simulateStaticDocuments = 0
config.tx_realurl_enable = 1
config.prefixLocalAnchors = all
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please provide us your Typoscript section of `config.` including your conditions made for those languages?

Another possibile problem: On your root page you should have declared all languages of the system. You have to make sure, that the UID of each language record equals to the number of your L Parameter in the URI or at least the `config.` for this language must match it.

Comment: Your "French" language record on your root page has the UID 1?

Comment: How can I check the config of my root page? (sorry, this is my first Typo3 project so I'm exploring everything at this moment). 

So I go to Web>Info? And then select: PageTSconfig?

Comment: Switch to the Backend module "List" an then click the uppest - real uppest - page in the page tree. Then you should see some records including your page languages. Hover the French records icon to see its UID.

Comment: Yes, when I hover the french icon I see: id=1.
Extra information/problem: When I use 'realurl' I've got the prefix '/en' when I click on 'FR'.

Comment: At first the language was German and Spanish, I removed it and then added French as a second language. Could it be that this is the cause? That in other words there is an incorrect link / reference in one or another file?

The default language was English, which I changed to Dutch. It is a bit strange now that when I click on 'FR' in the srt_languagemenu you will find it in the URL '/ en'.

I can use some help. Can I give someone access to my backend to watch?